# Validation react-materialize

Tags: reactjs, materialize

How I can create custom validation rule for TextInput in react-materialize?

```
    <TextInput
      validate
      email
      label="Email"
      error="Something wrong"
      success="Great"
    />
```

I need min length and email validation for this input. Email is default validation for react-materalize but with length I have problem